# Writing complex date recurrence in French

Tags: indications-de-temps, constructions, dates

I'm trying to generate natural sounding sentences representing complex calendar recurrences e.g.

> Every 1 month on the 4th Friday

and

> Every 2 years on the 1st Monday & Tuesday of January & February

Would the French sentence structure be similar enough to do a direct word for word translation?

e.g. Google Translate says:

> Chaque 1 mois sur le 4ème vendredi

and

> Tous les 2 ans sur le 1er lundi et mardi de Janvier et Février

Comment: Whether a word-for-word translation is "good enough" is up for debate, but it is certainly not the *best* way to phrase it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because of some points you cannot keep these translations. Here are several clues to correct them, knowing that they have to be generated. Toto has given best answers for the specific cases you presented, that are more nicely formulated.
Here are the errors in Google Translate :

- With days, `on` cannot be translated by `sur`. For example :

  > I play tennis on Monday.
  >
  > Je joue au tennis le lundi.

  Similarly,

  > On the 1st Monday
  >
  > Le 1er lundi
- There are two different translations, for singular & plural

  Singular :

  > Every 1 month
  >
  > Chaque mois

  Plural :

  > Every X months
  >
  > Tous les X mois
- If you have several days, you have to mark plural :

  > Every 2 years on the 1st Monday & Tuesday of January & February.
  >
  > Tous les deux ans **LES** 1er**s** lundis et mardis de janvier et février.

Comment: Je pense qu'on doit mettre un "s" à *lundi* et *mardi* vu qu'on parle de deux mois (et donc deux lundis et deux mardis).

Comment: By far the most educationnal answer :)

Comment: jiliagre & Simon are right, I edited my answer. Day's name is plural when the number of actual days it implies is plural too. In this sentence, they refer to two days each so they need a plural mark. More information in [http://parler-francais.eklablog.com/jours-de-la-semaine-a18608513] (french link).

Comment: Je pense que l'on doit mettre lundi et mardi au singulier. Mon raisonnement est le suivant : si on ne parlait que du lundi, on écrirait "le premier lundi de janvier et de février" (les premiers lundis aurait une autre signification) ; en rajoutant le mardi, on obtient donc : "le premier lundi et le premier mardi de janvier et de février", soit encore "les premiers lundi et mardi de janvier et de février". Je ne vois rien dans le lien sur parler-francais qui puisse aller dans l'autre sens, mais je peux bien sûr me tromper.

Comment: @Alexandre La phrase à laquelle je fais référence dans le lien était `La réunion a lieu tous les premiers mercredis du mois`, et donc en extrapolant : `La réunion a lieu les premiers lundis de janvier et février`

Comment: @Tac Je pense que c'est le "tous" qui fait la différence : `La réunion a lieu le premier mercredi du mois` ; `La réunion a lieu tous les premiers mercredis du mois` ; dans le cas qui nous occupe, il n'y a pas de "tous", donc le singulier me paraît plus logique. J'ai posé la question à l'auteur de ce blog, qui pourra peut-être nous éclairer.

Comment: @Alexandre Je suis d'accord que le "tous" peut avoir de l'importance. J'attends donc également la réponse de l'auteur.

Comment: @Tac Marc81 a répondu sur son billet. Il écrit : "On écrira : les premiers lundi et mardi de janvier, les premiers lundi et mardi de chaque mois, étant entendu qu’il n’y a qu’un premier lundi et qu’un premier mardi par mois.
Dans l’exemple que vous me soumettez, le singulier me semble également préférable puisque l’idée est la suivante : les premiers lundi et mardi du mois, de janvier à février. Toutefois, si l'on admet le pluriel dans tous les premiers lundis du mois, on ne peut le condamner ici, puisqu’il y aura bien plusieurs « premiers lundi et mardi du mois » dans la période concernée."

Answer (score 5):

There are different ways to say it but depending on the context, some will fit better than others. I wrote some ways here below.

The first sentence:

> Chaque quatrième vendredi du mois. (Each fourth Friday of the month)
>
> Tous les quatrièmes vendredi du mois. (Every fourth Fridays of the month)
>
> Le quatrième vendredi de chaque mois. (The fourth Friday of each month)

The second sentence:

> Chaque premier lundi et mardi de janvier et février, tous les deux ans.

But because we precise for which months and one year out of two, I prefer the following version:

> Les premiers lundi et mardi de janvier et février, un an sur deux.

Note that "un an sur deux" (one year out of two) and "tous les deux ans" (every two years) are interchangeable.

Comment: Les jours de la semaine doivent être au singulier ici car il n'y a qu'un quatrième vendredi du mois, et qu'un premier lundi et mardi, « Tous les quatrièmes vendredi du mois. » et « Les premiers lundi et mardi de janvier et février, un an sur deux. » Les nom de mois ne prennent pas de majuscule en français.

Comment: Les noms de mois de prennent pas de majuscule en français ; pour la deuxième traduction de la deuxième phrase, j'écrirais plutôt "les premiers lundi et mardi de janvier et février", puisqu'il n'y a qu'un premier lundi et un premier mardi par mois et qu'on écrirait "le premier lundi de janvier et février".

Comment: @jlliagre Merci pour ces corrections! Etes-vous sûre que pour janvier et février les jours ne sont pas au pluriel? Il y en un pour chaque mois donc 2 lundis et 2 mardis.

Comment: Je n'en suis plus sûr du tout, il y a bien en effet ici deux lundis et deux mardis...

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues Merci, j'ai édité ma réponse en prenant vos corrections en compte. Cependant j'ai une hésitation pour les lundis et mardis de janvier et février. Il me semble qu'ils doivent rester au pluriel...

Comment: @Remi je m'aperçois que mon message recoupait entièrement celui de jiliagre ! Je pense qu'on doit laisser lundi et mardi au singulier pour la raison suivante : si on ne parlait que du lundi, on écrirait "le premier lundi de janvier et de février" (les premiers lundis aurait une autre signification) ; en rajoutant le mardi, on obtient donc : "le premier lundi et le premier mardi de janvier et de février", soit encore "les premiers lundi et mardi de janvier et de février".

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues Merci pour l'explication! Je suis convaincu et m'en vais éditer (une fois de plus) ma réponse.

Comment: @Alexandred'Entraigues Merci d'avoir levé mon doûte !

Answer (score 3):

Pour la première expression, je dirais :

> Tous les quatrième vendredi de chaque mois.

Pour la deuxième :

> Les premiers lundi et mardi de janvier et février, une année sur deux.

Comment: Ou plutôt "janvier et février" sans majuscule.

Comment: Au temps pour moi, corrigé.

Comment: *quatrièmes* au pluriel et *vendredi* au singulier me semble incorrect. De même pour la seconde phrase.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps: d'accord pour la première phrase mais dans la seconde, premier s’accorde avec lundi **et** mardi

Comment: @Toto je ne prétends pas détenir la réponse, mais je me demande si, étant donné qu'on parle de deux mois (janvier et février), on ne devrait pas prendre en compte le fait qu'il y a deux lundis et deux mardis.